# How does .match and capturing group work together?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am supposed to make a regex to match numbers that appear three times in a string each separated by a space. But I don't know how .match() method and capturing group work.

So I have the following:

```js
let repeatNum = "42 42 42";
let reRegex = /(\d+)\s\1/; // Change this line
let result = repeatNum.match(reRegex);
console.log(result);
```

The result is:

```
["42 42", "42"]
```

Ok I kinda understand why the first element of this array is "42 42".

The regex:

```
/(\d+)\s\1/
```

means identify one or more number and a space. You put that word in group #1 and say find me another word after that space that is the same as what is group #1.

I have seen how this regex can work in a double-word example. But I don't know how it will work for three or more of the same number?

EDIT: I just found out the result is the same for 42 42 42 42. Now I am more confused.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask. There is no question in this post.

Comment: Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression). You may get what you require

Comment: T. J. Crowder thinks you want to match the whole string only. If he's wrong about that, then you'll need to make sure it doesn't match strings such as `"542 42 429"`. `\b` can help here: `/\b(\d+)\s\1\s\1\b/`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>JavaScript regular expression objects have no `match` method. You may be thinking of the one on *strings*:</s> *(Casimir et Hippolyte has changed it for you in the question)*

```js
let repeatNum = "42 42 42";
let reRegex = /(\d+)\s\1/; // Change this line
let result = repeatNum.match(reRegex);
console.log(result);
```

`String#match` returns an array containing the *overall match* as the first entry, followed by the content of any capture groups as subsequent entries in the array. That's why you get `["42 42", "42"]`: The `"42 42"` is the overall match for the expression, and the `"42"` is the content of the first capture group.

If you just want the overall match, simply use the first entry in the array.

> I am supposed to make a regex to match numbers that appear three times in a string each separated by a space.

Your regex won't do that. It will try to match the **same** number **twice** in a string.

If you want to match the **same** number three times, you just need another `\s\1`:

```js
let repeatNum = "42 42 42";
let reRegex = /(\d+)\s\1\s\1/;
let result = repeatNum.match(reRegex);
console.log(result ? result[0] : "No match");
```

If you just want to match numbers separated by spaces, the simplest thing is just to use `\d+\s\d+\s\d+`:

```js
let repeatNum = "42 43 44";
let reRegex = /\d+\s\d+\s\d+/;
let result = repeatNum.match(reRegex);
console.log(result ? result[0] : "No match");
```

...although you can use `\d+(?:\s\d+){2}` if you like, which says "A series of digits followed by two instances of: A space followed by a series of digits."

```js
let repeatNum = "42 43 44";
let reRegex = /\d+(?:\s\d+){2}/;
let result = repeatNum.match(reRegex);
console.log(result ? result[0] : "No match");
```

> I just found out the result is the same for 42 42 42 42

Without anchors, the regular expression will find matches within the string; it doesn't require that the match match the *entire* string. So when you run any of the above against `"42 42 42 42"`, you'll see the same thing as when you use it on `"42 42 42"`, because it matches a substring.

If you want to match *only* the whole thing, add `^` at the start and `$` at the end. Those are the beginning/end of input assertions.

For example, with the first change above (the minimal change to your regex):

```js
let repeatNum = "42 42 42";
let reRegex = /^(\d+)\s\1\s\1$/;
let result = repeatNum.match(reRegex);
console.log("repeatNum:", result ? result[0] : "No match");
let repeatNum2 = "42 42 42 42";
result = repeatNum2.match(reRegex);
console.log("repeatNum2:", result ? result[0] : "No match");
```

Comment: Sorry if my question is confusing. I was doing an assignment on an online course. And the instruction was muddy.